# How to get compliant policies data from aws inspector runs

Tags: amazon-web-services, inspector

I am trying to get policies compliance data from AWS inspector and able to get non-compliant data using boto3 API.

But now I want compliant policies data. 
**For example,** I have an AWS security group with RDP port(3389) opened to the internet so I am able to see `"AWS security group RPD port(3389) should not open to the internet"` policy is not compliant in the inspector.
But if the Security centre RDP port(3389) is closed then the same policy does not appear in the inspector findings.

 
So, is there any way to get all policies (i.e compliant & non-compliant) at the inspector findings?